# How to find ESXi host serial number using pyvmomi?

Tags: esxi, vcenter, pyvmomi

Previously for VCenter software version 6.0.0 I was using `vim.host.SystemIdentificationInfo` which was giving me the desired value inside `identifierValue`
But for VCenter software version 6.5.0 `vim.host.SystemIdentificationInfo` is returning me an empty list

Output:

> ```
> 'hardware': (vim.host.HardwareInfo) {
>
> dynamicType = <unset>,
>
> dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
>
> systemInfo = (vim.host.SystemInfo) {
>
>  dynamicType = <unset>,
>
>  dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
>
>  vendor = 'Cisco Systems Inc',
>
>  model = 'UCSB-B200-M4',
>
>  uuid = '16fa7876-059e-e711-0000-00000000001f',
>
>  otherIdentifyingInfo = (vim.host.SystemIdentificationInfo) []
>
>  }
> ```

However I am checking from the ESXi host cli I am getting the serial number by using the command:

> esxcfg-info | grep "Serial N"
>
> |----Serial Number............................................FLM1950CK2X

So, the value is available but not returned by pyvmomi currently.

Could anyone please help me to find it out?

Answer (score 0):

`host.hardware.systemInfo.serialNumber`